# Issues with '@' symbol in Excel formula when using OpenPyXL to write .xlsx file with INDEX functions

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl

I'm currently working on a Python script that utilizes OpenPyXL to write formulas to a .xlsx file. The specific formula I'm using involves the TEXTJOIN and INDEX functions. However, upon opening the saved .xlsx file in Excel, I noticed that an '@' symbol is automatically inserted before the INDEX function in the formula. This unexpected '@' symbol breaks the formula, and the formula only works as expected when I manually remove the '@' symbol.

Here's the code snippet I'm using to write the formula to the .xlsx file:

```
formula = '=_xlfn.TEXTJOIN(" + ", TRUE, IF(INDEX(Products!$B:$G, MATCH($A2, Products!$A:$A, 0), 0)=1, Products!$B$1:$G$1, ""))'

ws.cell(row=1, column=2, value=formula)
```

When I open the saved .xlsx file in Excel, the formula appears like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" + ", TRUE, IF(@INDEX(Products!$B:$G, 
MATCH($A2, Products!$A:$A, 0), 0)=1, Products!$B$1:$G$1, ""))
```

As you can see, the '@' symbol is causing the issue with the INDEX function in the formula.

I have already added the '_xlfn' prefix to the TEXTJOIN function to ensure it works properly, but I can't figure out why the '@' symbol is being inserted before the INDEX function. Could someone please explain why this is happening and suggest a solution to prevent the '@' symbol from being added to the formula?

Any insights or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The @ works with arrays instead of single cells. But what I tend to do is to paste those formulae as text - ie without the leading "=" and once pasted add t5he "=". I put "xyxyxy" in place of the "=" with edit:Find:Replace.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the comment. Do you have any ideas on how to include this solution in my Python script? It's essential that the output file meets the requirements and is perfectly functional as a spreadsheet when written down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to address this problem.

When dealing with array formulas in Excel using the `openpyxl` library, it's necessary to utilize the ArrayFormula class to properly handle them. Regular formulas are represented as strings, but array formulas require a more specific structure.

Here's an example:

```py
formula = '=_xlfn.TEXTJOIN(" + ", TRUE, IF(INDEX(Products!$B:$G, MATCH($A2, Products!$A:$A, 0), 0)=1, Products!$B$1:$G$1, ""))'
ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = ArrayFormula(ref="A1", text=formula)
```

By employing this approach, the formula in Excel becomes an array formula, and the unexpected insertion of '@' is avoided.